# Access to request parameter in custom logback appender

Tags: spring, logback

I have custom logback appender that is used in my project. The project is based on REST controllers.
Is there a possibility to have access to current request parameters in the logback appender that is used by logger in spring controller? I need to write something to logs in basis on the request parameter.
What I can see is that logback is initialized before spring boot beans which is not good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the org.slf4j.MDC: You can put values in the MDC at any time. Before anything else.
Example :

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/myRequest", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String doAnyAction(@RequestParam(value="Key", required = true) long key) 
{
        MDC.put("key", key);
        logger.info(key);
}
```

And change your Logback.xml appender to add the "key" as well :

```
<appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
  <layout>
    <Pattern>%X{key}  - %m%n</Pattern>
  </layout> 
</appender>
```